# setLngLat on marker doesn't work - mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I want to change current marker to new position.

```
let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: 'red', draggable: true })

  useEffect(() => {
    initMap()
  }, [])

  const initMap = () => {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '*******1g';
    if (mapboxgl.getRTLTextPluginStatus() !== 'loaded') {
      mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin(
        'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.2.3/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js',
        null,
        true // Lazy load the plugin
      );
    }

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [51.446558, 33.980739],
      zoom: 12,
      textAlign: 'left'
    });

    map.on('click', function (e) {
      var coordinates = e.lngLat;
      marker.setLngLat(coordinates).addTo(map); //this line does't setted.
  });


    setTimeout(() => {
      initMapMarker(map, 51.41691337396722, 34.022980413997786)
    }, 1000);
  }


  const initMapMarker = (map, initLon, initLat) => {

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    marker.setLngLat([initLon, initLat])
      .addTo(map);

    marker.on('dragend', () => {
      const lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
      getFormatedAddress(lngLat)

    });
  }
```

but after click on map this line did not work:

```
marker.setLngLat(coordinates).addTo(map);
```

It removed default marker.

Answer (score 0):

solved, import this line:

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
```